# file.write() sometimes (but not always) writing text to file

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, edit

I was using file.write() to add numerical data to a text file. However, after 516159 characters, something interesting happens: about half of the time I run my code, it drops the last 7k characters. The other half, it works fine.
Here is some code:

```
#Create or open file (it strangely couldn't create the file without using mode='x')
try:
  corpus_txt = open("corpus.txt", mode = "x")
except:
  corpus_txt = open("corpus.txt", mode = "w")

corpus_txt.truncate(0)#delete contents

content_length = 0

#X_train is a 2D array of integers
for sentence in X_train:
  for word in sentence:

    corpus_txt.write(str(word)+" ")
    content_length += len(str(word)+" ")

  corpus_txt.write("\n")
  content_length += 1

corpus_txt = open("corpus.txt")
content = corpus_txt.read()
corpus_txt.close()

print("FILE LENGTH (chars):", len(content))
print("TOTAL LENGTH OF TEXT ADDED TO FILE:", content_length)
```

When I run this repeatedly with my data:

- "content_length" always equals 523379
- len("content") alternates between the values 516247 and 523379

Some other information:

- The missing text occurs at the end of the data (the last 7k characters)
- It's not the increment of content_length at the newline
- My data is not altered during this code process
- I am using Google Colab
- I get 516k slightly more often than 523k
- There's no particular pattern for the switches
- It shouldn't be something about the formatting of the read() method because, once again, it's only the last 7k characters that are missing

I would greatly appreciate any help/explanation here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `close()` the file after you're finished writing to it; otherwise it's not guaranteed to be flushed to disk, and a subsequent `open()` won't "see" the writes you did.  Using the context manager syntax (`with open(...) as ...:`) is considered best practice precisely because it makes it almost impossible to make this kind of mistake.

This ought to work:

```
with open("corpus.txt", mode="w") as corpus_txt:

    # opening with "w" automatically overwrites previous contents
    content_length = 0

    #X_train is a 2D array of integers
    for sentence in X_train:
        for word in sentence:
            corpus_txt.write(str(word)+" ")
            content_length += len(str(word)+" ")
        corpus_txt.write("\n")
        content_length += 1

with open("corpus.txt") as corpus_txt:
    content = corpus_txt.read()

print("FILE LENGTH (chars):", len(content))
print("TOTAL LENGTH OF TEXT ADDED TO FILE:", content_length)
```

Unrelated to the file writing issue: I might suggest simplifying it down to just generate `content` as a string up front (since it's clearly small enough to fit in memory) so you don't need to have all the extra bookkeeping to figure out how long it is:

```
with open("corpus.txt", mode="w") as corpus_txt:
    content = "\n".join(
        " ".join(str(word) for word in sentence)
        for sentence in X_train
    ) + "\n"
    corpus_txt.write(content)
print(f"File length as written: {len(content)}")

with open("corpus.txt") as corpus_txt:
    content = corpus_txt.read()
print(f"File length as read: {len(content)}")
```

Comment: Doesn't calling `flush` and `fsync` guarantee it, too?

Comment: many ways to skin a cat, some significantly more perverse than others

Comment: Well I'm not saying it's better, just that I doubt the claimed "need" to close.

Comment: Technically you aren't "saying" anything at all, you're just pushing keys on a keyboard, which transmit information that I'm absorbing via my eyeballs.

Comment: Great, I appreciate it! I knew you had to call the close(), but I didn't realize open() wouldn't update the file if you called it before.